# Delphi - Get Number of dividable numbers

Tags: delphi, math, numbers, pascal, divide

I like to get the amount of numbers my target is dividable with.
So in case of 10 it should return 4, because 10 is dividable by 1,2,5 and 10.
My attemp was this, but it returns 1? O.o

```
function FindeTeiler(Zahl : Integer) : Integer;
var
Amount, i: Integer;
begin
  Amount := 0;
   For i := 1 to Zahl do begin
      If (i mod zahl = 0) then
      begin
        Amount := Amount +1;
      end;
   end;
   Result := Amount;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Showmessage('The number ' + Edit1.text + ' has ' + IntToStr(FindeTeiler(StrToInt(Edit1.text))) + ' dividers.');
end;
```

Comment: "So in the case of 10 it should return 10". Do you mean "it should return 4"? Also, I think you've got your `mod` statement backwards... try `if (zahl mod 1) = 0) then`

Comment: EDIT: Solved, it works like this: http://puu.sh/8Upz9/e0e17ee635.png

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, you shouldn't post an image of code. Just answer your own question. By the way, you don't need any parentheses around boolean expression in `if ... then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the remainder of zahl/i but your code calculates the remainder of i/zahl.

So, instead of

```
i mod zahl = 0
```

you need to test

```
zahl mod i = 0
```

The function should be written like so:

```
function FindeTeiler(Zahl: Integer): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Zahl do
    if zahl mod i = 0 then
      inc(Result);
end;
```

Comment: I think I would use an unsigned type for zahl here. An integer somehow implies that something useful happens when you feed a negative number.

Comment: To optimize that function I would start with `Result := 2;` and iterate from `2 to Abs( zahl div 2 )`

Comment: Actually, if Zahl is very large, it would suffice to iterate from 2 to Ceil(Sqrt(Zahl)).

Comment: @SirRufo You optimisation needs to cater for Zahl = 1.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh, s**t ...